# How to setup GitHub with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, git, github, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup a workflow that works for me. Developing wordpress sites

Basically I use dropbox to work on my local development...That way it's all backed up if computer crash or stolen. (So far working good)

I got Github account, created a Master REPO. And downloaded the GitBox software to push to this Master Repo (Worked Good so far)

Two questions I have:

1. How do I set it up so my wordpress database on local can be send to github and then when I push it to live server, it only updates the changes in the database?
2. How do I setup the ability to push my Github Master Repo to Live Server? I'm using AWS EC2 Instance.

So my work flow is

Local (development) > GitHub (Master Repo)
GitHub (Master Repo) > Live Server Production

If there is a better flow, I'm open to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Git (http://git-scm.com/) is only made for data. You can't commit databases. But you could create a mysqldump? Like this: [Synchronizing a MySQL Database with Git and Git Hooks](http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/)